# Don't know how "return ch[c-'A']"doing

Tags: c++

I don't know what "return ch[c-'A'];&return ch[c-'1'+26]; "doing.
The following are some code for uva401 - Palindromes in c++.

```
char ch[36]={'A',' ',' ',' ','3',' ',' ','H','I','L',
             ' ','J','M',' ','O',' ',' ',' ','2','T',
             'U','V','W','X','Y','5','1','S','E',' ',
             'Z',' ',' ','8',' '};
char rev(char);

char rev(char c){
  if (isalpha(c)){
    return ch[c-'A'];//this line I don't know what it means.
  } else {
    return ch[c-'1'+26];//this line I don't know what it means.
  } 
}
```

Comment: The [ASCII Table](https://www.asciitable.com/) will make things clear. Each character has an ASCII value. When dealing with alpha characters, if you need the character number (or offset, index, hamming-distrance, etc..) within either the upper or lower-case characters, you simply subtract either `'a'` or `'A'` from the current character.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that whoever wrote that function ASSUMED

- An ASCII or compatible character set, AND;
- Input is either an uppercase letter or a digit between `'1'` and `'9'`

Under those assumptions `c - 'A'`  will map the uppercase letters from `'A'` to `0`, `'B'` to `1`, `'C'` to `2`, .... `'Z'` to `25`  and `c-'1'+26` will map digit `'1'` to `26`, `'2'` to `27`, .... `'9'` to `34`.

The problem is that neither of those assumptions are guaranteed to be true.

There are real-world character sets that are not ASCII  (and do not have uppercase letters as a consecutive set).

Even with an ASCII (compatible) character set, there is nothing in the code to prevent a caller from passing a value to the function is outside the range of inputs for which the mapping makes sense.

It is not difficult to write code that is more clear and readable, checks if the input is valid, does the (presumably) intended mapping, and will behave as expected even with implementations that do not support an ASCII (or compatible) character set.   I'll leave writing such code as an exercise.

Comment: Instead of ASCII some computers like AS/400 use [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) where the code would be erroneous.

Answer (score 2):

Char variables in C++ are also represented by ASCII values for example, 'A' in ASCII is 65. So if char c = 'B' which equals 65 in ASCII increasing orderly in the alphabetical order, c - 'A' would mean 66 - 65 which equals 1. This value of 1 is then used as an index of the array ch to traverse the element at that index.

```
char ch[36]={'A',' ',' ',' ','3',' ',' ','H','I','L',
             ' ','J','M',' ','O',' ',' ',' ','2','T',
             'U','V','W','X','Y','5','1','S','E',' ',
             'Z',' ',' ','8',' '};

int c = 'B';
cout << ch[c - 'B']; //Output: A
```

[ASCII chart for all char variables](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii)

Answer (score 1):

Characters in C++ are represented by 8-bit integers (putting aside anything more complex than ASCII for now). For instance, `'a'` is `97`, and `'z'` is `122`.

We can do math with these, and they are automatically coerced into integers. Arrays are indexed by numbers, so we can use the result of this math to lookup an entry in an array.

Consider that `'A'` is `65`. If we subtract that from another capital character, we'll be left with how many characters into the alphabet we are. So `'E' - 'A'` evaluates to `4`.